# "encourage us to do so" or "encourage us"

Tags: phrase-choice

> 1. We are so worried about our appearance because
>      a lot of pressure are encouraging us **to do so.**
> 2. We are so worried about our appearance because a lot
>      of pressures are encouraging us.

The fact that confuse me is whether I need to add "to
do so" or not.  From only my point of view, I don't want to
add "to do so" as the sentence is clear in meaning without it.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving out "to do so" changes the meaning - in fact, it nearly reverses it.

Without an indirect object, "encourages us" means "cheers us on", "makes us feel hopeful", perhaps "makes us feel better about ourselves". This is very different from "makes us worry about our appearance".

Admittedly, the "because" makes it difficult to interpret "encourages us" in that way: to me, the result is a bit incoherent.